# how to remove null rows from column in mysql in order to move data to another db

Tags: mysql

I know there's information on this already but in my particular case the available resources I can find on it aren't working.

I'm trying to copy the data from a table in one database over to another table (also pre-existing) in another database. The table I'm trying to copy from contains null rows at the beginning which are preventing me from copying the data over because the second table will not allow null rows. I've tried deleting them, excluding them, including only the relevant rows, etc. Most of the stuff I've tried won't work with my particular version of mysql (syntax error). The specific error I'm getting when I try to move the data between databases is ERROR 1136.

mysql version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: we can't help you, since you haven't shown your query.

Comment: Please paste the entire error, not just an error number.

Comment: I didn't paste anything because I honestly don't know what to paste without pasting at *least* a dozen different command strings that I've tried with this. I was hoping that someone could give an example string to help get me going in the right direction. The only string that even remotely works is mysql -BN -p -e insert into "select serial from glpi_computers where serial is not null" glpi2 But that just gives me a list and I don't know where to go from there to get it in to the other database. Not to mention the null lines STILL show up even in that.